# file.save() doesn't save uploaded file on server - Flask, HTTP Request, Python

Tags: python, http, flask

I am developing a backend with python and a API with HTTP Requests to upload files. After uploading and submitting, the files should appear in the FLASK folder, but they don't. Where's my fault??

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os


folder = "/Documents/Coding/Flask"
extensions = set(['txt', 'jpg', 'png', 'pdf'])
app = Flask(__name__)


def allowed(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in extensions


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        if allowed(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(folder, filename))
            return redirect(request.url)

    return '''
        <h1>Upload</h1>
        <form method="post" enctpye="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" name="Upload">
    '''
```

Comment: check to make sure that the path is correct. You may want something like `folder = os.getwd() + "/uploads"`. `os.getcwd()` will get the absolute path no matter where the application is hosted

Answer (score 1):

Change your `folder` variable to this :

```
folder = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads') # Assigns upload path to variable
os.makedirs(folder, exists_ok=True) # Creates the directory,
```

And change your `file.save` to this :

```
file.save(os.path.join(folder, secure_filename(file.name)))
```

I think this will solve your problem .

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix my problem. It creates a folder "instance" with a subfolder "uploads". When I upload a file on localhost, it doesn't appear in the uploads folder.

Comment: Do you mean uploads folder into the instance folder ? Because it must be uploaded. Is there an error, or warning ?

Comment: It doesn't save the uploaded file anywhere. I can't find it. No errors, just trivial warnings. I don't get it

Comment: Can you print the `os.path.join(folder, secure_filename(file.name))` ?

Comment: how do I do that? I mean where do I put the print statement?

Comment: Just before your `file.save` function. I said it to check your directory .

Comment: There's no output ... it's not printing anything

Comment: As last hope, create a folder named `uploads` beside your folder, and change your save function to this : `file.save('uploads'+os.sep+secure_filename(file.name))`

Comment: And you put the print statement just above the `file.save` function right ? If it is not printed the output, that means if statement has blocked the `file.save`.

Comment: I don't know what I changed (I think nothing), but now everything is working. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking right now that problem was about allowed function. But if it is working right now,  no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you reach the "if allowed(file.filename):" statement. It's possible that the request ends before.

Comment: even if I outcomment the if-Statement, the file is not uploaded.